# Pytest and submodules

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I am trying to run pytest tests on my python modules but am running into an error. It looks like it the main script `ircFriend.py` can't find the modules I import inside of it. This is the error I get. I get this error on every test.

```
______________________________________________ ERROR collecting test/configuration_test.py ____________________________________
ImportError while importing test module 'C:\Users\munded\Desktop\irc-friend\test\configuration_test.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
..\..\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\importlib\__init__.py:127: in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
test\configuration_test.py:2: in <module>
    from src import ircFriend
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'configuration'
```

This is the file structure I am using for my tests. The `__init__.py` files are empty.

```
├───src
│   │   configuration.py
│   │   ircFriend.py
│   │   ircSync.py
│   │   logbook.py
│   │   networkdrive.py
│   │   server.py
│   │   tree.py
│   │   workspace.py
│   │   __init__.py
└───test
    │   configuration_test.py
    │   fileIO_test.py
    │   sandbox_test.py
    │   server_test.py
    │   sync_test.py
    │   __init__.py
```

If we look at the imports in `ircFriend.py` they look like this.

```
import sys
import getopt
import logging
from configuration import Configuration
from logbook import LogBook
from networkdrive import NetworkDrive
from ircSync import IRCSync
from workspace import Workspace
from server import Server
```

Finaly thees are what my tests look like.

```
from src import ircFriend
from unittest import mock
from src import configuration
from src import server


@mock.patch('builtins.input', side_effect=['X'])
def testPropertiesFileExists(mockInput):
    conf = Configuration()
    assert conf.propertiesFileExists() is True


@mock.patch('builtins.input', side_effect=['X'])
def testIrcConfigExists(mockInput):
    conf = Configuration()
    assert conf.ircConfigExists() is True


@mock.patch('builtins.input', side_effect=['devsite.dev', 'user'])
@mock.patch('src.ircFriend.getpass.getpass', return_value="IDK")
def testServerCreation(mock_input, mock_getpass):
    dev = Server()
    if isinstance(dev, ircFriend.Server):
        assert True
    else:
        assert False
```

Any guidence on this subject would do me a world of good.

Best Regards,
E

Comment: I am assuming that you are running the test from root of the module, Add a PYTHONPATH env with pytest command 
`PYTHONPATH=. pytest`
This is what has worked for me.

Comment: Sorry I still get the same error :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not make both `src/__init__.py` and `test/__init__.py` files because these src and test are not packages. These are just root directories for source and test codes.

In test codes, You should remove `from src` because `src` is not a package.

Finally,  run pytest adding src to PYTHONPATH otherwise pytest can't find modules under the src directory.

```
$ PYTHONPATH=src pytest test
```

Or, You can make `src/conftest.py`, this is a special file for pytest.

I checked these codes.

```py
# test/conftest.py
import sys
sys.path.append("./src")
```

```py
# src/a.py
from b import say
def func():
    return say()
```

```
# src/b.py
def say():
    return "Hello"
```

```
# test/test_a.py
import a
def test_a():
    assert a.func() == "Hello"
```

```
$ pytest test
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Took me some time to write all my tests to work with how you outline but it works like a charm now.

Comment: don't suggest modifying the path through `sys.path.append` it is bad practice. also OP can leave the `__init__` files and call the tests from the root of the repository by doing `python -m pytest test` which will automatically configure his path